# Converting future in multithreaded library

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am using a [simple multithreaded library](https://github.com/progschj/ThreadPool) to try and understand the basics.

The lib has a queueing function that looks like this:

```
auto enqueue(F&& f, Args&&... args) 
-> std::future<typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type>;
```

And stores functions like this:

```
std::queue< std::function<void()> > tasks;
```

There was an example on how to pass Lambdas, but i'd like to pass member variables. So i created a small object:

```
Threadpool tp(4);

class myClass{
  vector<std::future<int>> res;
public:
  int compute(int i){
    return 2 * i;
  };
  void update(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        res.emplace_back(
            // C2664 - 'std::future<int>::future(const std::future<int> &)': 
            // cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::future<_Rx>' to 'std::future<int> &&'
            tp.enqueue(std::bind(&myClass::compute, this), i)
        );
    };
  }
};
```

Creating an argumentless function works. But even the example lambda on the site works with a passed parameter:

```
tp.enqueue([](int answer) { return answer; }, 42);
```

What am I not getting here?

Also a side question: When it comes to standard functions what is the advantage of using:

```
auto fn(...) -> return type
```

instead of:

```
return type fn(...)
```

Comment: missing a placeholder in `bind`: `std::bind(&myClass::compute, this, /*std::placeholders::*/_1)`

Comment: trailing return type allows to use arguments in `decltype`, and allow to use scoped type (so `auto C::foo() -> iterator` instead of `typename C::iterator`)

Comment: Thank you for both answers, the missing placeholders was the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Placeholders is missing:

```
tp.enqueue(std::bind(&myClass::compute, this, std::placeholders::_1), i);
```

or simply

```
tp.enqueue(std::bind(&myClass::compute, this, i));
```

or with lambda

```
tp.enqueue([=]() { this->compute(i); });
```

Comment: @val: And maybe your library also supports `tp.enqueue(&myClass::compute, this, i);`.